# Database in version control using Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, schema, database-versioning

I've added a `SQL Server 2008` database project to my `Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition` solution in the hope that it might allow me to include my database in version control.

I can commit the schema files for each database object into version control, however these schema files all script objects as *create* rather than *alter*, so are not good for colleges getting my changes and updating their databases.

**Is this a good way to get my database into source control?**

**And what would the workflow be for actually using it to update databases to a given revision without losing all the data associated with dropping and re-creating all the tables?**

**Update:** on Premium and Ultimate versions, there is a schema compare tool which makes this easy.  This does not exist on Professional.  Is there any straightforward manual workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this in VS 2010 Professional, but in VS 2010 Premium, you can do a schema comparison (Data -> Schema Compare -> New Schema Comparison) between your project and database, and update changes in either direction.

When going from project to database, VS generates a script that copies existing data into a temporary table before dropping the existing one.

Comment: Thanks @adrift but sadly that option is not available in the Professional edition.

Comment: @Andy, sorry, that's a shame... it really does exactly what you're looking for :(

Comment: It does sound like what I need @adrift.  I'll accept your answer as no one has come up with a solution for the Professional edition.

Answer (score 1):

The database project has a deploy step (which is present in my Professional copy of VS2010) that will generate a sql script with your sql objects in it.

The key thing here is if you r-click the project, properties, goto deploy and change target database settings to a specific database, when you deploy it will generate a change script for that specific database so it matches the objects in the project (and in theory keep existing data etc).

You can get it to either generate a sql script, or directly update the database. Generating a script is probably a better idea :)

Comment: +1. Sounds promising.  I'll try it out as soon as I get a chance!